# Getting error to extract data from coinmarketcap

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import time
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np


df=pd.read_excel('currencynames.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('cryptodata.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
currencies = df['Currency Name']
print(currencies[0])
for i in range(0,1465,1):
    print("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"+currencies[i]+"/historical-data/?start=20130428&end="+time.strftime("%Y%m%d"))
    currency_market_info = pd.read_html("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/"+currencies[i].lower()+"/historical-data/?start=20130428&end="+time.strftime("%Y%m%d"))[0]
    currency_market_info = currency_market_info.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(currency_market_info['Date']))
    currency_market_info.loc[currency_market_info['Volume']=="-",'Volume']=0
    currency_market_info['Volume'] = currency_market_info['Volume'].astype('int64')
    currency_market_info.head()
    currency_market_info.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=currencies[i])
    currency_market_info = 0
    print("Done with "+currencies[i])
```

> C:\Users\SAU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py:816:
>   FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar
>   instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
>   result = getattr(x, name)(y) Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/SAU/Desktop/deep learning/cryptodata/data.py', wdir='C:/Users/SAU/Desktop/deep learning/cryptodata')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\SAU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 880, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\SAU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py",
>   line 102, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/SAU/Desktop/deep learning/cryptodata/data.py", line
>   19, in

```
currency_market_info.loc[currency_market_info['Volume']=="-",'Volume']=0
```

> File "C:\Users\SAU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py",
>   line 879, in wrapper
>       res = na_op(values, other)
>
> File "C:\Users\SAU\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py",
>   line 818, in na_op
>       raise TypeError("invalid type comparison")
>
> TypeError: invalid type comparison

Comment: i think you are comparing string with int, try changing    currency_market_info.loc[currency_market_info['Volume']=="-",'Volume']=0
TO     currency_market_info.loc[str(currency_market_info['Volume'])=="-",'Volume']=0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get good responses. In your case posting a snippet of the DataFrame before line 19 would go along way to creating a MCVE.